# How to do timecode calculation?

Tags: python, video, timecodes

I got a question regarding calculating time code delta.
I read metadata from a movie file containing a timecode formated `HH:MM:SS:FF`

(`FF` = frame, `00->23` for example. So its like `00` to `framerate-1`)

So i get some data like `15:41:08:02` and from another refrence file i get `15:41:07:00`
Now I have to calculate the timeoffset (like timedelta but just with frames).
How would i go around doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
framerate = 24

def timecode_to_frames(timecode):
    return sum(f * int(t) for f,t in zip((3600*framerate, 60*framerate, framerate, 1), timecode.split(':')))

print timecode_to_frames('15:41:08:02') - timecode_to_frames('15:41:07:00')
# returns 26

def frames_to_timecode(frames):
    return '{0:02d}:{1:02d}:{2:02d}:{3:02d}'.format(frames / (3600*framerate),
                                                    frames / (60*framerate) % 60,
                                                    frames / framerate % 60,
                                                    frames % framerate)

print frames_to_timecode(26)
# returns "00:00:01:02"
```

Comment: Thanks alot for all the quick answers everybody! Surprised how kind and fast people are here.

Answer (score 2):

I'd just use gobal frame numbers for all computations, converting back to timecodes only for display

```
def tc_to_frame(hh, mm, ss, ff):
    return ff + (ss + mm*60 + hh*3600) * frame_rate

def frame_to_tc(fn):
    ff = fn % frame_rate
    s = fn // frame_rate
    return (s // 3600, s // 60 % 60, s % 60, ff)
```

for negative frame numbers I'd prepend a minus to the representation of the absolute value

Answer (score 1):

If the timecode is [SMPTE timecode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMPTE_timecode), you may need to take into account drop frames. Drop-frame timecodes drop frame numbers 0 and 1 of the first second of every minute, except when the number of minutes is divisible by 10.

[This page](http://www.andrewduncan.ws/Timecodes/Timecodes.html) provides some history background with formulas to convert between timecodes and frame numbers.

Comment: For drop-frame timecode, the timeoffset between 01:08:59:29 and 01:09:00:02 should be 1, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Using the [timecode](https://github.com/eoyilmaz/timecode) module this is quite easy:

```
import timecode as tc
tc1 = tc.Timecode(24, "15:41:08:02")
tc2 = tc.Timecode(24, "15:41:07:00")
delta = tc1 - tc2
print(delta.frames)
```

gives you `26`